# Configuring nginx to listen on port a docker container is already running on

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a docker container that is listening on port 80 (and 443) running on a server and accepting request for a sub-domain `https://<subdomain1>.<domain>.com`

Now I need to deploy another container on the same server and accept connections for another subdomain `https://<subdomain2>.<domain>.com`. The problem is that the container for `subdomain1` is already running on port 80. For the new one, I can choose a different port on the host.

Is it possible to put nginx 'before' the container so it can redirect the traffic to different dockers accordingly? Also, ideally I wouldn't want to commit the old docker container and run it on a new port. I can stop and restart though.

Comment: Yes, can put a nginx reverse proxy in front of your web services with a server listening on port 80/443 with multiple virtual hosts (e.g. one for each subdomain). You will have to stop the container currently bound to port 80 to not conflict with the nginx server. The upstream services (e.g. your web services) should expose their ports within the docker network rather than mapping the ports to the host(s) on which the containers are running. If running in compose and nginx configured with upstream services you should add a depends_on to ensure those services are running before nginx starts.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a reverse proxy (serve at port 80 and 443), maybe [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) or Traefik stand in front of other containers.

This container will serve and redirect traffic to other Container running "random" port (not 80 and 443) like the image below.

[image]